# Regex Replace Cleaning a string from unwanted characters

Tags: regex, string, url-rewriting, replace

I'm creating a method to modify page titles into a good string for to use URL rewriting.
Example: "Latest news", would be "latest-news"

The problem is the page titles are out of my control and some are similar to the following:
Football & Rugby News!. Ideally this would become football-rugby-news.

I've done some work to get this to football-&-rugby-news!

Is there a possible regex to identify unwanted characters in there and the extra '-' ?

Basically, I need numbers and letters separated by a single '-'.

I only have basic knowledge of regex, and the best I could come up with was:

```
[^a-z0-9-]
```

I'm not sure if I'm being clear enough here.

Comment: note: the "&" character is also a reserved character in URLS.

Comment: yes i know, basically i want to remove any characters which aren't a letter, a number or a dash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a 'replace all' with something like this.

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+
```

Replace the matches with a dash.

Alternative regex:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

This one will avoid multiple dashes if a dash itself is found near other unwanted characters.

Comment: I was thinking of replacing with nothing, so it will just remove it, the problem is if i have a dash on both sides of the unwanted character I'll get 2. Should I pass it through 2 regexes maybe?

Comment: If you replace with nothing, you get 'footballrugbynews'. And I didn't understand your issue with dashes, but if you don't want too many dashes with your regex (like turning 'hey - look this' into 'hey---look-this'), remove the dash from the regex.

Comment: Great, maybe i didn't explain well, I was passing the string with dashes there, and I wanted to to keep the dashes. But the using the second regex on and replacing with dashes worked as I wanted it to. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This Perl script also does what you're looking for. Of course you'd have to feed it the string by some other means than just hardcoding it; I merely put it in there for the example.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "Football & Rugby News!";
$string = lc($string); # lowercase

my $allowed = qr/a-z0-9-\s/; # all permitted characters

$string =~ s/[^$allowed]//g; # remove all characters that are NOT in $allowed
$string =~ s/\s+/-/g; # replace all kinds of whitespace with '-'

print "$string\n";
```

prints

```
football-rugby-news
```